# htaccess remove part of URL after changing hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I got a little problem concerning my access to my owncloud on my synology. I got a subdomain called owncloud.xy.org for it and it works fine.

The Problem is that xy.org is redirected by an htaccess file (created by my own) to www.xy.org and this points to my web-folder. Owncloud ist default installed there too. So calling www.xy.org/owncloud starts also the login-page of owncloud.

I got that working by adding following rules to the htaccess-file in the owncloud folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !owncloud\.xy\.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xy
RewriteRule ^ https://owncloud.xy.org? [L,R=301]
```

Now if i create a share-link to a file by owncloud it creates one like this (which is fine):

```
https://owncloud.xy.org/index.php/s/UXju1jG0FJ0wMdq#pdfviewer
```

But if i change the Hostname-Part and add `/owncloud/` like this:

```
https://www.xy.org/owncloud/index.php/s/UXju1jG0FJ0wMdq#pdfviewer
```

It leads me to the Login-page with the following URL:

```
https://owncloud.xy.org/#pdfviewer
```

I think this behavior is normal, but how can i get rid of that #pdfviewer? Or does this happen due to my modifications in the htaccess-file?

Cheers